# Bootstrap 3: keep navbar items outside the collapse without wrapping to a new line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I could use some help getting my Bootstrap 3 navbar to look right when collapsed.

Apologies if this is a duplicate question but a good long search hasn't yielded the answers I need.

I've created a responsive navbar based on the Bootstrap demo code. In it, there's a 40x40 image and a globe glyph that link to dropdown menus, which I've right-aligned and omitted from the nav Collapse.

Unfortunately, the 40x40 and globe glyph appear on a new line when the nav collapses, which I don't want.

My perfect layout when the nav collapses would be for the 40x40 and globe to appear on the same line as my brand image, the collapse button etc; right aligned, and not contained in the collapse.

Thank you for any advice you can give!

Code is like so:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-hd-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="index.php"><img class="navbar-brand img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/138x38" alt="Logo"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav"  style="float: right; display: inline-block !important">
            <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="Profile Image" style="display: inline-block !important"/><b class="caret grey"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Hello</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="">Thing 1</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="">Thing 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav"   style="float: right; display: inline-block !important">
            <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe grey"></span><b class="caret grey"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li style="padding: 10px"><p>News</p></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

```
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-hd-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class="active"><a href="">Product</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Other Product</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Third Product</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </nav>
```

JS Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/CaraGee/q8br8/

Comment: Seems to be working solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037833/exclude-menu-item-from-the-collapse-of-bootstrap-3-navbar

Answer (score 1):

Add Style=" float:right"; in the 40*40 and globe div... so that the 40x40 and globe glyph appear on a same line

```
 <div class="navbar-right" style="float:right;">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="Profile Image" style="display: inline-block !important"/><b class="caret grey"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Hello</li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="">Thing 1</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="">Thing 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
     <div class="navbar-right" style="float:right">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe grey"></span><b class="caret grey"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li style="padding: 10px"><p>News</p></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Bala - you must have seen my origial, unedited question; sorry for the confusion. I came to a similar solution and updated my code / JSFiddle to show it - now I just need to know how to get those two things to show on the same line as the collapse button, if poss!

Comment: I have added bottom: -10px; in <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style=" bottom: -10px; ">  try this

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me Bala - but that edit doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

make a the collapse div with the align to the left:
and the non collapsable elements inside a div with the align to the right
like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- THIS WILL COLLAPSE-->
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-left">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- THIS WILL NOT COLLAPSE -->
            <div class="nav navbar-nav" >
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Conectarse</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This does not work.  It works fine in full screen but collapsed to mobile width the non collapse stuff does not stay on the same line as the responsive toggle button but rather drops down below it.

Comment: Yes I have seen the same issue too