# Best way to create Bootstrap 3 Navbar without wrapping text (and no collapse)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a Navbar with Bootstrap 3 that **doesn't collapse or wrap the text**. I'd like the text to simply be cut off (or ellipses) **instead of wrapping - so the Navbar remains on a single line without expanding vertically**. (this Navbar will be used to display the current view location with a single right-aligned menu)

Something like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">

    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
        <p class="navbar-text" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
            Trying to get this long line of text to not wrap even if too wide for the view to display. Trying to get this long line of text to not wrap even if too wide for the view to display.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
        <p class="navbar-text">Menu</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

As shown, I've been fooling with CSS float, overflow, whitespace settings and can't seem to get the right combination. Also, I'm using two navbar-header elements to avoid collapsing, but I'm open to other options if there is a better way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I did something like this two days ago. See my answer.

Comment: Isn't this like a major Bootstrap oversight?

Comment: Related: [Keep navbar items outside the collapse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761633/bootstrap-3-keep-navbar-items-outside-the-collapse-without-wrapping-to-a-new-li), [Exclude menu item from the collapse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037833/exclude-menu-item-from-the-collapse-of-bootstrap-3-navbar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/elezawA/1/

Here's a fixed version that works great: http://jsbin.com/elezawA/2

```
 body {
 padding-top: 50px;
}

.overflow {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  color:#ccc;
  max-width:90%;
}

  .overflow p {color:#ccc;line-height:50px;padding:0 10px;margin:0;display:inline;}


 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <span class="overflow">
       <p>
        Trying to get this long line of text to not wrap even if too wide for the view to display. Trying to get this long line of text to not wrap even if too wide for the view to display.
         </p> 
     </span>
   </div>

   <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
       <p class="navbar-text">Menu</p>
    </div>

 </div>
```

Going to have to fiddle with the percentage on the smaller widths to allow for the menu area. Do a min-width on this one and you'll figure it out. Perhaps add some padding to get it to not cover up. I will see later on today or tomorrow about this.

Comment: Thank you - this works great. I created it in jsFiddle before I saw your jsBin link http://jsfiddle.net/Ender2050/h27SD/1/.

Comment: It's that fixed position that will get you since there's not actual width on it since it bypasses the normal css stuff.

Comment: use the second link, it has some padding for smaller and a percentage for larger.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow javascript / jquery; add the overflow header to your .pull-left div too; `<div class="navbar-header pull-left" style="overflow: hidden;">`

and use this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.pull-left').css('max-width', ($( window ).width() - $('.pull-right').width()) + 'px');
});
```

See:  http://bootply.com/98610 
Note you will have to do recalculation on screen size changes using this solution.

If you could give your right nav a fixed width and allow ccs3 required you can do the same with:

```
.pull-left  
{   
/* Firefox */
max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 60px);
/* WebKit */
max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
/* Opera */
max-width: -o-calc(100% - 60px);
/* Standard */
max-width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
.pull-right{width:60px;}
```

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14101451/1596547

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.navbar-text` inline CSS, and use `white-space: normal` :

[image]

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">

    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
        <p class="navbar-text">
            Trying to get this long line of text to not wrap even if too wide for the view to display. Trying to get this long line of text to not wrap even if too wide for the view to display.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
        <p class="navbar-text">Menu</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
.navbar-text {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    white-space: normal
}
```

**[Bootply](http://bootply.com/98604#)**

Comment: Thank you - but I'm trying to get the text to NOT wrap as you've shown - so it appears all on a one-line Navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CSS3 property `text-warp` -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution that works in modern browsers - and as that page mentions, "The text-wrap property is not supported in any of the major browsers."