# Exclude menu item from the collapse of bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's what I have, I've tried moving around my section inside the "brand" and do a pull-right, outside the brand and outside the collapse and do a pull-left/right, while also trying to place it before or after the collapse section.

When adding it to the brand section it works, but it goes down to a new line. How do I keep it on the same line?

```
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation" style="font-size: 18px">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="navbar-brand site-title" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 24px; font-weight:bold">@Html.ActionLink("Manager", "Index", "Player")</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse navbar-right">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
@*                          <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Player")</li>
                            <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Match", "Index", "Match")</li>                             <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profile <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ManagePassword", "Account")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Update Profile Info", "UpdateProfile", "Account")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <!-- I don't want it apart of the collapsible portion -->
                        <div class="navbar-right">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Match", "Index", "Match")</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Comment: Please provide some details about your goal, what you are trying to achieve is not clear (an simple picture showing the desired layout would be useful)

Comment: @zessx sorry, just saw this. I have about 8 menu items in my navigation bar. There's one main menu item that I want accessible without having to click the drop-down button on the navbar because it's a link that will be used ALOT on mobile devices. Therefore, I don't want the user to have to go through any extra "clicks/touches" to get to that menu item. The answer below will work for me, I just need to do some more formatting so it doesn't overlap with the drop-down menu button.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Below is an example that shows how to have just about any kind of 'vanilla bootstrap' NAVBAR configuration you could want.  It includes a site title, both collapsing and non-collapsing menu items aligned left or right, and static text.  Be sure to read the comments to get a fuller understanding of what you can change.  Enjoy!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nomis/n9KtL/1/

Fiddle with clearfix and expanded options on left side like normal: http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/u1j8o0n3/1/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">GNOMIS</a>
    </div>

    <!-- 'Sticky' (non-collapsing) right-side menu item(s) -->
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
      <ul class="nav pull-left">
        <!-- This works well for static text, like a username -->
        <li class="navbar-text pull-left">User Name</li>
        <!-- Add any additional bootstrap header items.  This is a drop-down from an icon -->
        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#777; margin-top: 5px;" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="/users/id" title="Profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/logout" title="Logout">Logout </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Required bootstrap placeholder for the collapsed menu -->
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- The Collapsing items            navbar-left or navbar-right -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
      <!--                      pull-right keeps the drop-down in line -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="/news">News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/Shop">Shop</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Additional navbar items -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <!--                      pull-right keeps the drop-down in line -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="/locator">Locator</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/extras">Extras</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Great answer and very helpful comments. I have a followup question related to this: Do you *have* to have a collapsing section? What if I only want static items that I control the visibility of with the 'hidden-' and 'visible-' classes?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks!  I did a deep dive on the bootstrap menus and figured I'd share.  No you don't need any collapsing items.  Any element with the `navbar-header` class will not collapse!

Comment: @nomis, This works, but can you explain why you need the "margin-top: 5px" in the dropdown header?

Comment: @Andrew.  Good question.  The reason is that the icon is larger than the text, so if I add the usual `navbar-text` class, which is what centers the other text elements in the navbar with 15px of top and bottom margin, it makes the navbar a lot wider than it should be.  So you either have to find a way to make the icon smaller, or add the custom padding (5px;) and not include the `navbar-text` class.

Comment: This works great, but I head problems aligning navbar-text and links (I did not use dropdown on the non-collapsible part). My solution was different CSS quirk: `@media(max-width: 767px) { .navbar-text { margin-top: 10px; } }`. When others are not collapsed, that margin would be 15px, but once they collapsed, I had misallignments. Not sure why this is needed, but works.

Comment: This is now broken. Here is a working example based on the above http://www.bootply.com/V46gEMiBa3

Comment: @MichaelPlotke comment works, but the original works now too.  One problem with the original fiddle is that the collapsed menu appears in the middle of the screen instead of below, fixed in @MichaelPlotke's with a div with a classes `clearfix visible-xs-block`.

Answer (score 28):

You should be able to use `pull-left` and `pull-right` in 2 `nav-header`'s to prevent the link from collapsing.

See: http://bootply.com/104747

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
        <div class="navbar-brand">Brand</div>
      </div>

      <!-- I don't want it apart of the collapsible portion -->
      <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
          <li class="active"><a href="">No Collapse</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profile <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>Change Password</li>
              <li>Update Profile Info</li>
              <li>Log Off</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: That looks great. Looks like there's a slight bit of overlap after it's been collapsed. Do you know how to fix that (like adding a margin-right ONLY after it's collapsed?). I thought I tried the dual headers, pull-left and pull-right already, but probably not together. Great answer!!! I will try and incorporate this tonight when I get home from work.

Comment: @Skelly, great answer, just wish it was easier to read the poorly formatted html!

Comment: Of course the HTML was from the OP ;-) -- I updated the Bootply.

Comment: @nomis which part is poorly formatted? I'm very OCD about my code styling and feel this is the easiest way to read it...

Comment: This doesn't work if there's more than 1 <li> in <ul>

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any more. When you expand the collapsed menu items, it shows the items over on the left on top of the branding.

Comment: This doesn't work for me; links get overlapped on top of one another.

Comment: Works correctly when  <div class="visible-xs-block clearfix"></div> is added directly before  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">. This is how Michael Plotke does it on his comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my other answer in Jade with some template logic just for fun :).  See the other answer for additional info.

```
//- NOTE:        'navbar-default' styles the 'burger' and navbar text color, so remove it to add your own
nav(class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top", role="navigation")
  .container

    //- Title
    .navbar-header.pull-left
      a.navbar-brand(href='javascript:window.location.replace(window.location.origin);') GNOMIS

    //- 'Sticky' (non-collapsing) right-side menu item(s) 
    .navbar-header.pull-right
      ul.nav.pull-left
        //- This works well for static text, maybe some initials
        li.navbar-text.pull-left User Name
        //- User Icon drop-down menu
        li.dropdown.pull-right
          a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown', style="color:#777; margin-top: 5px;")
            span.glyphicon.glyphicon-user
            b.caret
          ul.dropdown-menu
              li
                a(href="/users/id", title="Profile") 
                  | &nbsp;&nbsp;Profile
              li
                a(href="/logout", title="Logout")
                  | &nbsp;&nbsp;Logout 

      //- Required bootstrap placeholder for the collapsed menu    
      button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.navbar-collapse')
        span.sr-only Toggle navigation
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar

    //- The Collapsing items  navbar-left or navbar-right
    .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-left
      //-               pull-right keeps the drop-down in line
      ul.nav.navbar-nav.pull-right
        li
          a(href="/news") News
        li
          a(href="/shop") Shop

    //- Additional navbar items
    .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-right
      //-               pull-right keeps the drop-down in line
      ul.nav.navbar-nav.pull-right
        li
          a(href="/locator") Locator
        li
          a(href="/extras") Extras
```