# Leave Textbox out of navbar but still responsive (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, responsive

I am trying to customize the default bootstrap navbar by leaving the textbox and submit button out - but still responsive-. The thing is that when I make the screen smaller -and the other buttons collapse- the texbotx automatically jumps to another line. I'd like for it to stay in the same line, and compress to adjust to the size of the screen.
I tried using rows but I couldn't figure out how to put it in practice. Also, I tried to follow the answer for this post [Exclude menu item from the collapse of bootstrap 3 navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037833/exclude-menu-item-from-the-collapse-of-bootstrap-3-navbar)
but it wouldn't work for the form.

Any help will be welcomed! Thanks for reading:)

I don't think this is going to be any helpful, but here's my html code.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
  <nav class="my-navbar navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left ">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
    
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        
      </form>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      </ul>
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Idioma<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Perfil</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Configuració <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
 </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: so you want that form on same line on small screen.Check  one  [ https://jsfiddle.net/25qs8o8L/ ] check the css part. hope this will help you. Good luck

Comment: @MostafaBaezid this worked!!! looks like magic, thank you so much! Now I have to try to understand why, but I think I can manage it. Thanks :)