# Keep links in navbar at collapsing using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm creating a responsible navigation bar using Bootstrap. Now it looks like:

[image]

in **expanded** view, and:

[image]

in **collapsed** view.

In the normal view it looks okay, however in collapsed view I'd like to keep in the bar *Sign Up* links and **not to have it** in the collapsed list. Something like this (this screenshot was created in graphical editor):

[image]

This is my code:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aqgtmy6w/4/

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037833/exclude-menu-item-from-the-collapse-of-bootstrap-3-navbar) but collapsed list there is broken, some links shifted left and right.

How can I achieve keeping some links in navbar on collapsing, and how to exclude them from list (so that not to duplicate them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `sing up` link inside `<div class="navbar-header">` and add `class="navbar-brand pull-right"` to your sign up link. That's it.

**Working Snippet**

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@media(min-width:768px){
#sm-view {
display:none;
}
}
@media(max-width:767px){
#lg-view {
display:none;

}
#sm-view {
font-size: 14px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      <a id="sm-view" class="navbar-brand pull-right"  href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li id="lg-view"><a   href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

To have same styling as the nav-links and not like the navbar-brand just add this--- `#sm-view {font-size: 14px;}` to your media query  `@media(max-width:767px)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, your code really works for collapsed view. But in the case of expanded view, the SignUp link is pulled left before the Home link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sLCP.png Is it possible to keep it on the right in expanded view as I'm currently have?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..according to me the best way to achieve it is to use media queries..updated the snippet please check.

Comment: I just need one more small favor. Now in collapsed view a SignUp link style is the same as WebSiteName, it is `navbar-brand`. When I try to remove it or change to `navbar-nav`, it looks very ugly with absolutely different style https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxtIu.png. Could you suggest how to fix it?

Comment: check the updated answer if this helps..in this way you can style the link as you wish

Comment: thanks, Bootstrap is awesome, but to do a really nice tricks a certain practice is required.