# Layout in the bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

my goal is to have several parts of the navigation:

1. LOGO
2. notification icon
3. language selector
4. The proper menu.

On big screens all of the should be visible.
On small screens:

1. LOGO
2. notification
3. language selector AND the menu are collapsed

I have managed to achieve the functionalty based on:
[Exclude menu item from the collapse of bootstrap 3 navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037833/exclude-menu-item-from-the-collapse-of-bootstrap-3-navbar)

This is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/papa_zulu/0efL781p/3//

and the code:

```
<body>
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>

      </div>

      <!-- 'Sticky' (non-collapsing) right-side menu item(s) -->
      <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
        <ul class="nav pull-left">
          <!-- This works well for static text, like a username -->
          <li class="navbar-text pull-left"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Required bootstrap placeholder for the collapsed menu -->
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
      </div>

      <!-- Fix to make collapsed appear below when visible via button -->
      <div class="visible-xs-block clearfix"></div>

      <!-- Collapsing section to the left -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Collapsing section to the right -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li id="menu_home"><a class="nav" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fw fa-2x"></i><span class="visible-xs-inline menu-xs-caption">Home</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu_setup"><a class="nav" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fw fa-2x"></i><span class="visible-xs-inline menu-xs-caption">Settings</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu_logout_li"><a class="nav" href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i><span class="visible-xs-inline menu-xs-caption">Logout</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">We are but visitors on this rock, hurling through time and space at sixty-six thousand miles an hour.</div>
  </div>
```

Notice:
The notification icon is located LEFT of the "expand button" on small screen -- this is correct.

The problem:
I would like BOTH the notification icon AND the language selector to be located to the LEFT of the menu on big screens.

So the layout on big screens should be:

```
LOGO                     envelope flag all_themenu_icons
```

and one small screens:

```
LOGO             envelope button          <-- this is correct now
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yorkford/qnh6L5kv/6/)

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
```

```
<!-- Title -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>

  <!-- Required bootstrap placeholder for the collapsed menu -->
  <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <ul class="nav visible-xs  pull-right">
    <!-- This works well for static text, like a username -->
    <li class="navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Fix to make collapsed appear below when visible via button -->


<!-- Collapsing section to the right -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-main">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="navbar-text hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li id="menu_home"><a class="nav" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fw fa-2x"></i><span class="visible-xs-inline menu-xs-caption">Home</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu_setup"><a class="nav" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fw fa-2x"></i><span class="visible-xs-inline menu-xs-caption">Settings</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu_logout_li"><a class="nav" href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i><span class="visible-xs-inline menu-xs-caption">Logout</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```