# Navbar with collapsible and non collapsible elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a navbar in bootstrap that shows like the following image on desktop. (image 1)

[image]

And on mobile I wish to collapse it as shown in image 2 sketch.

[image]

For this I used the code as follows with bootstrap.

```
<div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Post</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>

</div>
```

The image in mobile view is what I want when screen size reduced, so that only glyphicons are showed.

Please let me know your ideas as I am new to this.
[JsFiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Set789/s5qzg7du/)

Comment: I found a closer answer here. But it does not solve the issue with showing only glyphicons in the mobile view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761633/bootstrap-3-keep-navbar-items-outside-the-collapse-without-wrapping-to-a-new-li

Comment: The JSFiddle isnt working

Comment: JSFiddle external resources for bootstrap css needs fix

Comment: @DanielJacobson  JSFiddle external sources fixed and now working.

Comment: @Urielzen JSFiddle external sources fixed and now working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of one way to acheive this: the `nav` is restructured into columns in order to account for the right icons that are fixed.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper .navbar-default {
  border: transparent;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #266080;
  height: 56px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  right: 35%;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.login {
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.login .glyphicon {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.login p {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-content {
  padding: 0 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .login .glyphicon {
    padding: 10px 0px;
  }
  .login {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-8">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
      <!--end nav-->
    </div>
    <!--end col9-->
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-4">
      <div class="login">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-nav"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
          <p class="hidden-xs">Profile</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-nav"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
          <p class="hidden-xs">Post</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end col3-->
  </div>
  <!--end row-->
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
<div class="main-content">
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </p>
</div>
```